# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when using output from Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a dictionary data I add a key and value like so:

```
data['business-details'] = "{{ service.business_details }}";
```

this is from django and the content has a comma `,` which I believe is causing the code to crash.
Getting this error on the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

which goes to this line

```
data['business-details'] = "I can design both front and back (Django) end for a site, preferably interesting projects.";
```

[image]

Comment: Looks more like you have newline that puts `";` on the next line?

Comment: ^ To fix that `trim()` your output from django, or use backticks to create a template literal , as they can handle line breaks *within* the string

Comment: ok then triple quotes should do since I can't trim text that's intended to be edited later.